# How to compile OpenSSL libraries for specific deployment macOS version?

Tags: macos, deployment, compilation, openssl, version

I am compiling OpenSSL libraries on macOS 10.15, but my application deployment target (which uses these OpenSSL libraries) is 10.12.
So, when I link these libraries with my application I get multiple errors like this:

```
ld: warning: object file (.../libcrypto.a) was built for newer OXS version (10.15) than being linked (10.12)
```

The question is:
how to compile OpenSSL to be linked with specific deployment target (in my case it is 10.12)?

When compiling OpenSSL I am trying to configure it like this:

```
$ ./configure darwin64-x86_64-cc --prefix=/Users/username/openssl --openssldir=/Users/username/openssl/ssl -mmacosx-version-min=10.12
```

but this does not help.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I did not execute the command:

```
$ make distclean
```

at the end of my previous compilation.

So, it should look like this:

```
$ ./configure darwin64-x86_64-cc --prefix=/Users/username/openssl --openssldir=/Users/username/openssl/ssl -mmacosx-version-min=10.12
$ make depend
$ make install
$ make distclean
```

Then all temporary files will be deleted and next compilations with modified sittings will work.

Comment: I'm trying to get it working by simply setting the environment variable MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to (in my case) 10.13. But, when I link to the openssl build from my app, the compiler throws me this warning `d: warning: object file (/usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-bio_lib.o)) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.13)`. Any idea what's going on?